# Ionic Web Builder cant find an ionic module?

Tags: angular, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework, npm

I am trying to build my ionic app with their own web build system and in my app.component.ts file i am importing this:

```
import { File } from '@ionic-native/File/ngx';
```

This project builds locally just fine and the npm package for @ionic-native/File is definitely in my package.json file. What could be the issue here?

[image]

Comment: check package.json and add this dependency. Then do `npm install` or `npm i`

Comment: I mentioned in my post that it is already in my package.json

Comment: What is this "web build system" you mention? What commands are you running?

Comment: @janpio the ionic web builder that they offer in their online dashbaord https://dashboard.ionicframework.com which can build your cordova project for you and deploy builds

Comment: You mean Ionic Deploy of the Ionic Appflow product then @labago

Comment: @janpio yes that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in your import I think no?

```
import { File } from '@ionic-native/File/ngx';
```

should be

```
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file/ngx';
```

/**F**ile/ => /**f**ile/

If still doesn't work, remove add your native libs

```
npm rm @ionic-native/file @ionic-native/core --save
npm install @ionic-native/file @ionic-native/core --save
```

Comment: This fixed it thank you! Weird that it doesn't matter locally

Comment: Windows locally? That doesn't care about localization of file (which this is used to load from), Linux and macOS do care :(

Comment: @janpio yes I am on a windows environment, so that makes sense. Thanks for the tip!